# How to connect an MI bluetooth mouse to a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, mouse

How can I connect an MI Bluetooth mouse a to mac book pro ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What have you tried so far?  Please see [ask] for important info regarding asking questions here.

Comment: It might connect automatically  ...mouse click blue-tooth symbol on menu bar (2 triangles together) -> mouse click open bluetooth preferences -> turn on blue tooth -> mouse should now show in list -> click connect. If the mouse doesn't show its bluetooth will need "activating" (small circular button underside of mouse)

Answer (score 1):

From [Mi Mouse manual](https://files.xiaomi-mi.com/files/mi_mouse/mimouse-EN.pdf) :

1. Turn on the Bluetooth function on the computer
2. Hold down the ''connection mode'' button, until indicator light turns on
3. On your computer find this Bluetooth device (on bluetooth preferences, device name : MiMouse)
4. Press "connect" for accomplishment of connection of the device

Note that your computer need a Bluetooth chip version BCM20702 and above, and system operating 10.10 or later.